# The measure of number integers not greater $n$ is finitely additive not $\sigma$-additive?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mu_n(A)$ be the number of integers in $A\subset \mathbb Z$ not greater than $n$. Let $\mathcal F$ be the family of sets $A$ for which $\mu(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mu_n(A)}{n}=L$ exists, then $\mu$ is finitely additive but not $\sigma$-additive.

I am confused about this question because I don't understand what $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mu(A_n)}{n}=L$  means or how I can use it to solve the question.

Comment: You are using $A$ with two  different meanings. Change the limit to some other symbol.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, like this $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mu(A_n)}{n}=B$ you mean?

Comment: I assume, that with $\lim_{n\to\infty}\tfrac{\mu_n(A)} n$ is wanted, that $\tfrac{\mu_n (A)}n$ is an converging sequence. We need this, because otherwise $\mu(A)$ would not be well-defined.